# Include non-Solution items in Nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I have created a Nuspec file with the following `files` elements:

```
<files>
    <file src="lib\" target="lib" />
    <file src="tools\" target="tools" />
    <file src="content\" target="content" />
    <file src="other-stuff\" target="content" />
</files>
```

When I restore this Nuget package to any project, the contents of the `other-stuff` folder is added to the project (as expected).

Is there any way to ensure this content is placed on the filesystem, **but not added to the project / solution?** I don't want this content to show in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to create a folder with no content in the nuspec file. However, you can definitely do this using a install.ps1 file. You can find many examples by searching for "nuget install.ps1" and utilizing powershell code to create a directory.